# Is Delphi jvclHidDevice ReportID the equivalent of USB endpoint?

Tags: delphi, usb, hid

I can make USB HID work in Delphi (2010) for simple stuff (one endpoint, ReportID = 0).

But now I need to send 96 words (192 bytes) of data every millisecond. I see how to do that in the slave (PICmicro) with three 64 byte endpoints. (Full speed Interrupt transfer is limited to 64 bytes per endpoint.) But I don't see either a more flexible USB/Delphi object or a way to specify endpoints in the JvclHIDDeviceController object.

Is ReportID telling me the received endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

> Is ReportID telling me the received endpoint?

No. When used, it is the first of the 64 (maximum) data bytes.

> I need to send 96 words (192 bytes) of data every millisecond

Using WinUSB (or LibUSB-win32) and a bulk pipe sounds simpler to me than trying to create and access a composite device with 3 HID interfaces.